# SLD format in modern OpenLayers library

Tags: openlayers

It seems like old versions of OpenLayers [supported](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/sld.html) SLD format. There was a construct like:

```
var format = new OpenLayers.Format.SLD();
```

But I cannot find it in modern OpenLayers library. I checked [ol.format](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/apidoc/ol.format.html) and see that there is no `ol.format.SLD()`.  Why is that? Was it replaced by another format (some which is better than SLD)?

Comment: Please see [this issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2954).